# angular view not rendering in laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I want to render an angular view in laravel but angular is unable to display my views. This is my main angular template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-model="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        function getBaseURL () {
            return location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/";
        }
        <script type="text/javascript">var baseUrl = window.location.origin</script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript">window.base_url = <?php echo json_encode(base_url('/')); ?>;</script> -->
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular-cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my script (app.js)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'main.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    });
});
```

This is my html (about.html)

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>

    <p>This is the about page</p>
</div>
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return File::get(public_path().'/angular-templates/main.html');
})->where('angular', '.*');
```

Angular is able to render the main.html page but not the about.html.

Comment: Have you defined an `aboutController` or `contactConroller`?

Comment: @AlexLogan, please how do i do that. i have created `aboutController.js` and `contactController.js`. how do i do that?

Comment: Look at this tutorial. https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating.

Comment: @AlexLogan, yeah that was the tutorial i was following. ok i have clean my code and started all over again with that same tutorial but i keep getting this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:`

Comment: That's a PHP problem I can't help you with...

Comment: ok, i have been able to make the main.html render. but the `<div ng-view></div>` is not able to inject the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing `<html ng-app="myApp">`, i wrote `ng-model="myApp"` and this messed up the whole thing. Thank you guys all your contributions helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register controllers for the about and contact pages to your app. Your app is called `myApp`, so in the `aboutController.js` file, the first line should be:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('aboutController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
//controller logic goes here
}]);
```

And the same for your `contactController.js`

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    //controller logic goes here
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you guys i fixed it. I wrote <html ng-model="myApp"> instead of writing `<html ng-app="myApp">` . Your contributions helped in one way or the other.